# How can I proxy through a SOCKS5 a openssl socket in C?

Tags: c, sockets, proxy, openssl

I tried looking at OpenSSL github source code but that did not help.

I need something so that when I call the SSL_CTX initialization like this:

```
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method, proxy);
```

And then use it to make connections and send data it gets sent through the proxy.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no builtin functionality for this. But once you've created a TCP connection over SOCK5 you can simply use the socksified socket in SSL_set_fd and then do SSL_connect.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look into that.